# Endpoints Portal with Auht0 authentication

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-endpoints

I try to setup endpoints portal with auht0 authentication. The problem is i don't see the Api Explorer Settings in the portal settings.

All requirements are implemented.

Any idea what the problem is?

Comment: Can you check your browser's developers console for any error messages (F12 in Chrome)? This may give a clearer hint as to what is causing this section not to be shown.

Comment: The only thing that is shown in this "app.js:628 Unsupported auth type for API Explorer auth0_jwt oauth2
t.getApiSecurityUsages @ app.js:628". But I got this message also in the Api Explorer with the Message, click here to configure.

Comment: I have posted the question to the Endpoints dev group: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-cloud-endpoints/xNdpeAVPado

Comment: @Aron I see that the question has issue has been solved in the endpoints dev group. Could you please post the solution here? The community would benefit greatly from this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now, in the developer portal, we only handle Auth0 in a specific case --- if your security definition ID is named exactly "auth0_jwk" (slight change from your "auth0_jwt"). If you want to use Auth0 in the portal immediately and you're willing to change that ID in your spec, that should resolve the issue.

On our end, we'll try to make the portal more robust in recognizing when you're using Auth0 in your specification, likely based on the issuer field. We'll have that fix in coming weeks.

Hope that helps!

Comment: It's been 30 weeks and Auth0 still isn't available unless you change your security definition id. When is it coming out?